# How to skip sequential row observations?

Tags: r, row, skip

I have a data set comprised of 5 minute price observations (not an xts set) as follows:

```
dat = read.csv("olddat.csv", as.is=TRUE);
tim = strptime(dat[,1], "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M");
dat$day = format(tim, "%Y-%m-%d");
##ddx <- row index for each day
ddx = split(seq.int(nrow(dat)), dat$day);
```

that returns:(this is only one day of data that I copied in from R and the observations on each day usually carry on until 23:55, the entire set has many more days)

```
2423  24/11/2011 00:00 1.3356 2011-11-24
2424  24/11/2011 00:05 1.3356 2011-11-24
2425  24/11/2011 00:10 1.3356 2011-11-24
2426  24/11/2011 00:15 1.3359 2011-11-24
2427  24/11/2011 00:20 1.3363 2011-11-24
2428  24/11/2011 00:25 1.3364 2011-11-24
2429  24/11/2011 00:30 1.3364 2011-11-24
2430  24/11/2011 00:35 1.3362 2011-11-24
2431  24/11/2011 00:40 1.3362 2011-11-24
2432  24/11/2011 00:45 1.3361 2011-11-24
2433  24/11/2011 00:50 1.3357 2011-11-24
2434  24/11/2011 00:55 1.3361 2011-11-24
2435  24/11/2011 01:00 1.3365 2011-11-24
2436  24/11/2011 01:05 1.3367 2011-11-24
2437  24/11/2011 01:10 1.3368 2011-11-24
2438  24/11/2011 01:15 1.3365 2011-11-24
2439  24/11/2011 01:20 1.3364 2011-11-24
2440  24/11/2011 01:25 1.3366 2011-11-24
2441  24/11/2011 01:30 1.3369 2011-11-24
2442  24/11/2011 01:35 1.3369 2011-11-24
2443  24/11/2011 01:40 1.3369 2011-11-24
2444  24/11/2011 01:45 1.3367 2011-11-24
2445  24/11/2011 01:50 1.3368 2011-11-24
2446  24/11/2011 01:55 1.3367 2011-11-24
2447  24/11/2011 02:00 1.3367 2011-11-24
2448  24/11/2011 02:05 1.3365 2011-11-24
2449  24/11/2011 02:10 1.3365 2011-11-24
2450  24/11/2011 02:15 1.3372 2011-11-24
2451  24/11/2011 02:20 1.3373 2011-11-24
2452  24/11/2011 02:25 1.3376 2011-11-24
2453  24/11/2011 02:30 1.3376 2011-11-24
2454  24/11/2011 02:35 1.3379 2011-11-24
2455  24/11/2011 02:40 1.3379 2011-11-24
2456  24/11/2011 02:45 1.3378 2011-11-24
2457  24/11/2011 02:50 1.3378 2011-11-24
2458  24/11/2011 02:55 1.3377 2011-11-24
2459  24/11/2011 03:00 1.3377 2011-11-24
2460  24/11/2011 03:05 1.3377 2011-11-24
2461  24/11/2011 03:10 1.3379 2011-11-24
2462  24/11/2011 03:15 1.3384 2011-11-24
2463  24/11/2011 03:20 1.3383 2011-11-24
2464  24/11/2011 03:25 1.3382 2011-11-24
2465  24/11/2011 03:30 1.3382 2011-11-24
2466  24/11/2011 03:35 1.3383 2011-11-24
2467  24/11/2011 03:40 1.3383 2011-11-24
2468  24/11/2011 03:45 1.3381 2011-11-24
2469  24/11/2011 03:50 1.3380 2011-11-24
2470  24/11/2011 03:55 1.3381 2011-11-24
2471  24/11/2011 04:00 1.3383 2011-11-24
2472  24/11/2011 04:05 1.3381 2011-11-24
2473  24/11/2011 04:10 1.3382 2011-11-24
2474  24/11/2011 04:15 1.3381 2011-11-24
2475  24/11/2011 04:20 1.3379 2011-11-24
2476  24/11/2011 04:25 1.3379 2011-11-24
2477  24/11/2011 04:30 1.3379 2011-11-24
2478  24/11/2011 04:35 1.3373 2011-11-24
2479  24/11/2011 04:40 1.3373 2011-11-24
2480  24/11/2011 04:45 1.3371 2011-11-24
2481  24/11/2011 04:50 1.3368 2011-11-24
2482  24/11/2011 04:55 1.3369 2011-11-24
2483  24/11/2011 05:00 1.3373 2011-11-24
2484  24/11/2011 05:05 1.3373 2011-11-24
2485  24/11/2011 05:10 1.3372 2011-11-24
2486  24/11/2011 05:15 1.3373 2011-11-24
2487  24/11/2011 05:20 1.3376 2011-11-24
2488  24/11/2011 05:25 1.3376 2011-11-24
2489  24/11/2011 05:30 1.3375 2011-11-24
2490  24/11/2011 05:35 1.3374 2011-11-24
2491  24/11/2011 05:40 1.3371 2011-11-24
2492  24/11/2011 05:45 1.3367 2011-11-24
2493  24/11/2011 05:50 1.3364 2011-11-24
2494  24/11/2011 05:55 1.3363 2011-11-24
2495  24/11/2011 06:00 1.3361 2011-11-24
2496  24/11/2011 06:05 1.3360 2011-11-24
2497  24/11/2011 06:10 1.3362 2011-11-24
2498  24/11/2011 06:15 1.3364 2011-11-24
2499  24/11/2011 06:20 1.3362 2011-11-24
2500  24/11/2011 06:25 1.3364 2011-11-24
2501  24/11/2011 06:30 1.3366 2011-11-24
2502  24/11/2011 06:35 1.3366 2011-11-24
2503  24/11/2011 06:40 1.3366 2011-11-24
2504  24/11/2011 06:45 1.3369 2011-11-24
2505  24/11/2011 06:50 1.3377 2011-11-24
2506  24/11/2011 06:55 1.3376 2011-11-24
2507  24/11/2011 07:00 1.3388 2011-11-24
2508  24/11/2011 07:05 1.3391 2011-11-24
2509  24/11/2011 07:10 1.3394 2011-11-24
2510  24/11/2011 07:15 1.3389 2011-11-24
2511  24/11/2011 07:20 1.3390 2011-11-24
2512  24/11/2011 07:25 1.3386 2011-11-24
2513  24/11/2011 07:30 1.3387 2011-11-24
2514  24/11/2011 07:35 1.3387 2011-11-24
2515  24/11/2011 07:40 1.3392 2011-11-24
2516  24/11/2011 07:45 1.3390 2011-11-24
2517  24/11/2011 07:50 1.3392 2011-11-24
2518  24/11/2011 07:55 1.3383 2011-11-24
2519  24/11/2011 08:00 1.3378 2011-11-24
2520  24/11/2011 08:05 1.3377 2011-11-24
2521  24/11/2011 08:10 1.3377 2011-11-24
2522  24/11/2011 08:15 1.3375 2011-11-24
2523  24/11/2011 08:20 1.3373 2011-11-24
2524  24/11/2011 08:25 1.3377 2011-11-24
2525  24/11/2011 08:30 1.3380 2011-11-24
2526  24/11/2011 08:35 1.3378 2011-11-24
2527  24/11/2011 08:40 1.3378 2011-11-24
2528  24/11/2011 08:45 1.3379 2011-11-24
2529  24/11/2011 08:50 1.3378 2011-11-24
2530  24/11/2011 08:55 1.3376 2011-11-24
2531  24/11/2011 09:00 1.3394 2011-11-24
2532  24/11/2011 09:05 1.3391 2011-11-24
2533  24/11/2011 09:10 1.3402 2011-11-24
2534  24/11/2011 09:15 1.3406 2011-11-24
2535  24/11/2011 09:20 1.3399 2011-11-24
2536  24/11/2011 09:25 1.3394 2011-11-24
2537  24/11/2011 09:30 1.3397 2011-11-24
2538  24/11/2011 09:35 1.3405 2011-11-24
2539  24/11/2011 09:40 1.3412 2011-11-24
2540  24/11/2011 09:45 1.3405 2011-11-24
2541  24/11/2011 09:50 1.3403 2011-11-24
2542  24/11/2011 09:55 1.3398 2011-11-24
2543  24/11/2011 10:00 1.3402 2011-11-24
2544  24/11/2011 10:05 1.3392 2011-11-24
2545  24/11/2011 10:10 1.3384 2011-11-24
2546  24/11/2011 10:15 1.3384 2011-11-24
2547  24/11/2011 10:20 1.3375 2011-11-24
2548  24/11/2011 10:25 1.3377 2011-11-24
2549  24/11/2011 10:30 1.3377 2011-11-24
2550  24/11/2011 10:35 1.3379 2011-11-24
2551  24/11/2011 10:40 1.3378 2011-11-24
2552  24/11/2011 10:45 1.3371 2011-11-24
2553  24/11/2011 10:50 1.3373 2011-11-24
2554  24/11/2011 10:55 1.3375 2011-11-24
2555  24/11/2011 11:00 1.3372 2011-11-24
2556  24/11/2011 11:05 1.3379 2011-11-24
2557  24/11/2011 11:10 1.3383 2011-11-24
2558  24/11/2011 11:15 1.3382 2011-11-24
2559  24/11/2011 11:20 1.3382 2011-11-24
2560  24/11/2011 11:25 1.3387 2011-11-24
2561  24/11/2011 11:30 1.3387 2011-11-24
2562  24/11/2011 11:35 1.3383 2011-11-24
2563  24/11/2011 11:40 1.3383 2011-11-24
2564  24/11/2011 11:45 1.3390 2011-11-24
2565  24/11/2011 11:50 1.3391 2011-11-24
2566  24/11/2011 11:55 1.3394 2011-11-24
2567  24/11/2011 12:00 1.3409 2011-11-24
2568  24/11/2011 12:05 1.3401 2011-11-24
2569  24/11/2011 12:10 1.3401 2011-11-24
2570  24/11/2011 12:15 1.3392 2011-11-24
2571  24/11/2011 12:20 1.3388 2011-11-24
2572  24/11/2011 12:25 1.3388 2011-11-24
2573  24/11/2011 12:30 1.3383 2011-11-24
2574  24/11/2011 12:35 1.3388 2011-11-24
2575  24/11/2011 12:40 1.3393 2011-11-24
2576  24/11/2011 12:45 1.3389 2011-11-24
2577  24/11/2011 12:50 1.3382 2011-11-24
2578  24/11/2011 12:55 1.3374 2011-11-24
2579  24/11/2011 13:00 1.3374 2011-11-24
2580  24/11/2011 13:05 1.3368 2011-11-24
2581  24/11/2011 13:10 1.3373 2011-11-24
2582  24/11/2011 13:15 1.3373 2011-11-24
2583  24/11/2011 13:20 1.3378 2011-11-24
2584  24/11/2011 13:25 1.3381 2011-11-24
2585  24/11/2011 13:30 1.3386 2011-11-24
2586  24/11/2011 13:35 1.3372 2011-11-24
2587  24/11/2011 13:40 1.3361 2011-11-24
2588  24/11/2011 13:45 1.3345 2011-11-24
2589  24/11/2011 13:50 1.3338 2011-11-24
2590  24/11/2011 13:55 1.3338 2011-11-24
2591  24/11/2011 14:00 1.3346 2011-11-24
2592  24/11/2011 14:05 1.3345 2011-11-24
2593  24/11/2011 14:10 1.3343 2011-11-24
2594  24/11/2011 14:15 1.3343 2011-11-24
2595  24/11/2011 14:20 1.3342 2011-11-24
2596  24/11/2011 14:25 1.3337 2011-11-24
2597  24/11/2011 14:30 1.3329 2011-11-24
2598  24/11/2011 14:35 1.3330 2011-11-24
2599  24/11/2011 14:40 1.3329 2011-11-24
2600  24/11/2011 14:45 1.3327 2011-11-24
2601  24/11/2011 14:50 1.3333 2011-11-24
2602  24/11/2011 14:55 1.3336 2011-11-24
2603  24/11/2011 15:00 1.3334 2011-11-24
2604  24/11/2011 15:05 1.3327 2011-11-24
2605  24/11/2011 15:10 1.3330 2011-11-24
2606  24/11/2011 15:15 1.3330 2011-11-24
2607  24/11/2011 15:20 1.3331 2011-11-24
2608  24/11/2011 15:25 1.3338 2011-11-24
2609  24/11/2011 15:30 1.3338 2011-11-24
2610  24/11/2011 15:35 1.3336 2011-11-24
2611  24/11/2011 15:40 1.3330 2011-11-24
2612  24/11/2011 15:45 1.3335 2011-11-24
2613  24/11/2011 15:50 1.3335 2011-11-24
2614  24/11/2011 15:55 1.3331 2011-11-24
2615  24/11/2011 16:00 1.3329 2011-11-24
2616  24/11/2011 16:05 1.3332 2011-11-24
2617  24/11/2011 16:10 1.3330 2011-11-24
2618  24/11/2011 16:15 1.3332 2011-11-24
2619  24/11/2011 16:20 1.3335 2011-11-24
2620  24/11/2011 16:25 1.3333 2011-11-24
2621  24/11/2011 16:30 1.3330 2011-11-24
2622  24/11/2011 16:35 1.3329 2011-11-24
2623  24/11/2011 16:40 1.3333 2011-11-24
2624  24/11/2011 16:45 1.3339 2011-11-24
2625  24/11/2011 16:50 1.3337 2011-11-24
2626  24/11/2011 16:55 1.3341 2011-11-24
2627  24/11/2011 17:00 1.3344 2011-11-24
2628  24/11/2011 17:05 1.3354 2011-11-24
2629  24/11/2011 17:10 1.3353 2011-11-24
2630  24/11/2011 17:15 1.3348 2011-11-24
2631  24/11/2011 17:20 1.3345 2011-11-24
2632  24/11/2011 17:25 1.3344 2011-11-24
2633  24/11/2011 17:30 1.3345 2011-11-24
2634  24/11/2011 17:35 1.3346 2011-11-24
2635  24/11/2011 17:40 1.3345 2011-11-24
2636  24/11/2011 17:45 1.3342 2011-11-24
2637  24/11/2011 17:50 1.3338 2011-11-24
2638  24/11/2011 17:55 1.3340 2011-11-24
2639  24/11/2011 18:00 1.3341 2011-11-24
2640  24/11/2011 18:05 1.3339 2011-11-24
2641  24/11/2011 18:10 1.3339 2011-11-24
2642  24/11/2011 18:15 1.3339 2011-11-24
2643  24/11/2011 18:20 1.3342 2011-11-24
2644  24/11/2011 18:25 1.3341 2011-11-24
2645  24/11/2011 18:30 1.3341 2011-11-24
2646  24/11/2011 18:35 1.3342 2011-11-24
2647  24/11/2011 18:40 1.3342 2011-11-24
2648  24/11/2011 18:45 1.3341 2011-11-24
2649  24/11/2011 18:50 1.3343 2011-11-24
2650  24/11/2011 18:55 1.3342 2011-11-24
2651  24/11/2011 19:00 1.3342 2011-11-24
2652  24/11/2011 19:05 1.3341 2011-11-24
2653  24/11/2011 19:10 1.3340 2011-11-24
2654  24/11/2011 19:15 1.3339 2011-11-24
2655  24/11/2011 19:20 1.3338 2011-11-24
2656  24/11/2011 19:25 1.3337 2011-11-24
2657  24/11/2011 19:30 1.3336 2011-11-24
2658  24/11/2011 19:35 1.3337 2011-11-24
2659  24/11/2011 19:40 1.3337 2011-11-24
2660  24/11/2011 19:45 1.3335 2011-11-24
2661  24/11/2011 19:50 1.3338 2011-11-24
2662  24/11/2011 19:55 1.3335 2011-11-24
2663  24/11/2011 20:00 1.3334 2011-11-24
2664  24/11/2011 20:05 1.3334 2011-11-24
2665  24/11/2011 20:10 1.3339 2011-11-24
2666  24/11/2011 20:15 1.3339 2011-11-24
2667  24/11/2011 20:20 1.3346 2011-11-24
2668  24/11/2011 20:25 1.3349 2011-11-24
2669  24/11/2011 20:30 1.3342 2011-11-24
2670  24/11/2011 20:35 1.3345 2011-11-24
2671  24/11/2011 20:40 1.3347 2011-11-24
2672  24/11/2011 20:45 1.3349 2011-11-24
2673  24/11/2011 20:50 1.3349 2011-11-24
2674  24/11/2011 20:55 1.3349 2011-11-24
2675  24/11/2011 21:00 1.3349 2011-11-24
2676  24/11/2011 21:05 1.3348 2011-11-24
2677  24/11/2011 21:10 1.3349 2011-11-24
2678  24/11/2011 21:15 1.3348 2011-11-24
2679  24/11/2011 21:20 1.3348 2011-11-24
2680  24/11/2011 21:25 1.3348 2011-11-24
2681  24/11/2011 21:30 1.3348 2011-11-24
2682  24/11/2011 21:35 1.3348 2011-11-24
2683  24/11/2011 21:40 1.3346 2011-11-24
2684  24/11/2011 21:45 1.3346 2011-11-24
2685  24/11/2011 21:50 1.3347 2011-11-24
2686  24/11/2011 21:55 1.3348 2011-11-24
2687  24/11/2011 22:00 1.3354 2011-11-24
2688  24/11/2011 22:05 1.3353 2011-11-24
2689  24/11/2011 22:10 1.3349 2011-11-24
2690  24/11/2011 22:15 1.3352 2011-11-24
2691  24/11/2011 22:20 1.3348 2011-11-24
2692  24/11/2011 22:25 1.3348 2011-11-24
2693  24/11/2011 22:30 1.3349 2011-11-24
2694  24/11/2011 22:35 1.3350 2011-11-24
2695  24/11/2011 22:40 1.3348 2011-11-24
2696  24/11/2011 22:45 1.3348 2011-11-24
2697  24/11/2011 22:50 1.3347 2011-11-24
2698  24/11/2011 22:55 1.3347 2011-11-24
2699  24/11/2011 23:00 1.3345 2011-11-24
2700  24/11/2011 23:05 1.3345 2011-11-24
2701  24/11/2011 23:10 1.3345 2011-11-24
2702  24/11/2011 23:15 1.3341 2011-11-24
2703  24/11/2011 23:20 1.3339 2011-11-24
2704  24/11/2011 23:25 1.3337 2011-11-24
2705  24/11/2011 23:30 1.3338 2011-11-24
2706  24/11/2011 23:35 1.3337 2011-11-24
2707  24/11/2011 23:40 1.3341 2011-11-24
2708  24/11/2011 23:45 1.3338 2011-11-24
2709  24/11/2011 23:50 1.3335 2011-11-24
2710  24/11/2011 23:55 1.3331 2011-11-24
```

The 5 minute observations were already in place when the data was downloaded. I am basically just wondering how can I modify this data to obtain observations at every 10 minutes, 15 minutes, 30 minutes and one hour, i.e. to sequentially drop rows when reading in the data without having to manually delete each undesired row at one at a time through MSExcel and then read in the data?

Comment: Do you mean something like `dat[seq(1, nrow(dat), by = ###), ]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 res <- 2 
 ## 2 for one every 10min (i. e. one every 2 rows), 
 ## 3 for one every 15min (i. e. one every 3 rows), etc.
 dat[seq(1, nrow(dat), by=res), ]
```

**Edit following comments:**

```
res <- 2
split(dat, dat$day, drop=TRUE) -> d1 
##Split into days
lapply(d1, FUN=function(x) {x[seq(1, nrow(x), by=res), ]->x}) -> d1 
##Select one observation every 10min for each day separately
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, d1)) -> result
##Re-aggregate into one single dataframe (you may need to reset the row names though)
```

Comment: Hi thanks, this works a charm for the most part but unfortunately some of my data is not 'perfect' in that when I add the above code it cuts off data on days that end at e.g. 22:10 and therefore skips 00:00 on the next day thereby sampling at the 'wrong' observations over every second day. Do you know any way to stop this? thanks

Comment: The simple answer would be to separate in a first step your dataset in days, then pick one observations every 10min as above, and then reaggregate all the days together afterwards. There may be a way to avoid going to this trouble but I don't see it right now...

Comment: cheers, yeah that's what i was fearing would be the case. thanks for your help